# « C'était » ou « C'étaient » dans une tournure présentative ?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, accord

À l'image de :

> C'est un historien. (singulier)
>   Ce sont des historiens. (pluriel)

Qu'en est-il de la forme passée pour le pluriel ? Doit-on écrire la première phrase ou la seconde ?

> 1) C'était des historiens.
>   2) C'étaient des historiens.

Comment: Pour ton premier exemple, tu ne pensais pas à « C'est des historiens » plutôt ?

Comment: Dans tous les cas, passé ou pas passé, de mon point de vue, ça ne change rien à l'affaire.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Tu veux dire que *le temps ne fait rien à l'affaire?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En fait, les deux phrases conviennent.

Ta deuxième proposition est ce qu'il y a de plus littéraire. La première proposition reflète plus une tournure que tout le monde utilise actuellement par abus de langage.

Le Bon usage explique qu'en écrivant **« c'était des chats noirs »**, **c'était** a la valeur d'un présentatif et en l'occurence, on utilise de plus en plus **c'était** comme présentatif.

> C'était de grands garçons. (langue familière)
>   C'étaient de grands garçons. (langue littéraire)

À toi de voir ce que tu préfères. Moi je penche davantage sur la forme plus littéraire. En revanche, lorsque tu utilises **nous** ou **vous**, on mettra toujours **c'est** bien que nous et vous soient des personnes du pluriel.

> C'est nous qui sommes de garde demain soir.

Comment: Par analogie avec les maths (« Soit E et F, des espaces topologiques »), selon les contextes, *c'était* peut mieux me plaire.

Comment: @Evpok Il y a des mathématiciens qui écrivent « soient ».

Comment: @Gilles Oui, mais de là à taxer « c'était » de familier…

Answer (score 0):

Je préfère considérer que le vrai sujet est le " c' ", et le reste l'attribut, donc toujours mettre le verbe au singulier.

De plus, certains mots ou locutions de présentation, en tête d'une phrase, sont toujours invariables :

"Vu vos nombreuses lettres, ..."

"Etant donné deux droites parallèles, ... "

Comment: « Vu » et « étant donné » ne sont pas toujours invariables, ça dépend des locuteurs.